# defaultdict appending list of list rather than list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, defaultdict

I am trying to use collections.defaultdict in python 3.
I tried following steps in console:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> dd["one"].append(l)
>>> print(dd)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'one': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]})
```

As, you can see its adding `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` i.e. list of list so I need two for loops to read its variables.

Why it is not appending something like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`??

Is there something wrong with my implementation or understanding how defaultdict works?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `append` adds the object you are passing in to the list, i think you want to be using `extend`

Comment: Thanks @RNar, it worked.
Can you put your comment in answer I will upvote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with my implementation or understanding how defaultdict works?

Not at all. Your code work exactly as expected. A default value of an empty list was created, and you `.append` a single element to that list: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Actually, this isn't really related to `defaultdict` at all. It's perfectly fine for a list to contain a list. `.append`ing a list to another list is not some special operation. It's the same as appending any other element such as `1` or `'hello`. The *entire* list you `.append`ed is consider a *single* element.

If you want to add the *elements* of an iterable to your list, you should use [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead:

> Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to `a[len(a):] = iterable`.

```
dd["one"].extend(l)
```